# Symmetry product in Grothendieck ring of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Assume that two smooth quasi-projective vareities $X,Y$ have the same class in the Grothendieck ring of varieties.

> Do the symmetry products $X^{(n)}$ and $Y^{(n)}$ also have the same class?

Moreover, if there are some feasible criteria to judge if two varieties have the same class?

Edit: I leave this part of original the question as well as the answer as a complete closed post.

Comment: Please confer, "An exponential function on the set of varieties" by Gusein-Zade, Luengo, Melle-Hernandez: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206279.pdf

Comment: Actually, although the formulation by Gusein-Zade, et al., is novel, the result you ask seems to go back to Kapranov in his definition of the motivic zeta function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a quick explanation.  Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.  Let $\mathcal{Var}_k$ denote the set of (embedded) quasi-projective $k$-varieties.  The Grothendieck group of varieties, $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)$, is the quotient of the free Abelian group on $\mathcal{Var}_k$ by all relations, $$[X] = [U]+[C],$$ if $C$ is $k$-isomorphic to a closed subvariety of $X$ whose open complement is $k$-isomorphic to $U$.  This is actually a commutative ring under the product $[X]\cdot [Y] = [X\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} Y]$.  The identity element is $1=[\text{Spec}\ k]$.

Inside the power series ring $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)[[t]]$, the subset of power series whose constant coefficient equals $1$ is an Abelian group under multiplication; call this group $G$.
For every $X$ in $\mathcal{Var}_k$, Kapranov defines an element in $G$, the **motivic zeta function**, $$\zeta_X(t) = 1 + \sum_{n\geq 1}[\text{Sym}^n(X)]t^n.$$
For every integer $n\geq 1$, there is a partition of $\text{Sym}^n(X)$ into locally closed subsets $Z_{n,m}$ for $m=0,\dots,n$, where $Z_{n,m}$ denotes the subvariety parameterizing length $n$ zero-cycles on $X$ whose intersection with $U$ has length precisely $m$.  Then the "residual" zero-cycle is a length $n-m$ zero-cycle supported on $C$.  In this way we get a $k$-isomorphism, $$Z_{n,m} \cong \text{Sym}^m(U)\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\text{Sym}^{n-m}(C).$$
This is precisely the same as the identity, $$\zeta_X(t) = \zeta_U(t)\cdot \zeta_C(t).$$  Thus, the zeta function from $\mathcal{Var}_k$ to the Abelian group $G$ satisfies the relations to factor through a group homomorphism from $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)$, $$\zeta:K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k) \to (1+tK_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)[[t]])^\times.$$  In particular, the motivic zeta function $\zeta_X(t)$
only depends on the class of $X$ in $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)$.  Consequently, for every integer $n\geq 1$, the class $[\text{Sym}^n(X)]$ in $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)$ only depends on the class of $X$ in $K_0(\mathcal{Var}_k)$.

Comment: "the set function" (after the fourth display) should be "the zeta function", I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Sasha.  I fixed it.